# How to return a resource count in a REST API?

Tags: api, rest, resources, get, count

Let's say I have a REST API, which has basic methods to retrieve users and the photos of a user. For example:

```
// Get a user:
GET /user/123

// Get the photos of a user:
GET /user/123/photos

// Get a photo:
GET /photo/789
```

This is quite straightforward, however now I also need a method to retrieve the number of photos for a particular user. I don't want to retrieve all the photos because that would slow everything down and is not necessary. What would be the best way to do that in a REST API?

I thought about implementing something like `GET /user/123/photo_count` however "photo_count" is not a resource so that doesn't seem right.

How would I go about presenting this kind of information properly in a REST API?

Comment: Couldn't photo count be a property of the user returned by GET /user/123?

Comment: @Ameen, that's how I ended up doing it, it's a clean solution and it makes sense to have the count as a property. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comment on the original post, you can return the photo count as a property of your user "object". The `GET /user/123` call would simply return an object/json/xml that contains the number of pictures as a property.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Get the photos of a user: 
GET /user/123/photos
```

This does not have to actually return the photos, it could return just a list of links.

It could even be a partial list of the first n links with information on the total number, and links to get the next/prev batch.

Comment: Most likely it will return a list of IDs, but it could potentially be thousands of ID, which is not really scalable. Also I want to avoid returning anything that is not needed since this is for a mobile web application.

Comment: Many API's do what @Szocske is suggesting with something like this <results page="1" total="1043" resultPerPage="50">

Answer (score 4):

You could do something a little "custom" like returning the count as a response header. Then to just get the count you would issue a [HEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAD_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) which should return the headers with no response body (i.e.. not actually load the photos).

```
GET /user/123/photos
==>
Headers:
X-Count 23
Body:
<photos>
<photo id="1">...</photo>
<photo id="2">...</photo>
...
</photos>

HEAD  /user/123/photos
==>
Headers:
X-Count 23
Body:
none
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting technique. I wonder if this is a common pattern to return this kind of metadata in the header? Are there any potential drawbacks?

Comment: The only drawback I can think of would be that this is not "standard" REST and that the client needs to be aware of that functionality (by reading some documentation) to use it. Otherwise that should work well. There's also a standard way of paging in HTTP using special request headers and 206 response code. You might be able to use it in a way to achieve something similar: http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/.